# Dynamic Mysql query Not give right result

Tags: php, mysql

i have mysql query like this

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT

  GROUP_CONCAT(
      'fvalue AS ',x.name
  ) INTO @sql

from reimbursment x
LEFT JOIN reimbursment_limit y
ON y.acc_code = x.acc_code;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT b.firstname, ', @sql, ' from user b
left join reimbursment_limit c
  on b.id = c.user_id
left join reimbursment d
  on c.acc_code = d.acc_code
group by b.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

and table like this,

user

```
id nip    firstname
1  123456 AAAAA
2  999999 BBBBB
```

reimbursment

```
id acc_code name
1  22002    Dentis
2  22004    Allowance
```

reimbursment limit

```
id user_id acc_code fvalue
1  1       22002    500000
2  1       22004    700000
```

and result, like this

```
firstname Dentis Allowance
AAAAA     500000 500000
BBBBB     null   null
```

The right result, must

```
firstname Dentis Allowance
AAAAA     500000 700000
BBBBB     null   null
```

this query is workig, but not give the right result where the allowance for user AAAAA is must 700000, how fix the result?i have try anything but still not give right result.

Thank you

Comment: i think right relation is that: on b.nip = c.user_id

Comment: @devpro : thankyou sory i'm wrong create question, i have been edit my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the join an group by

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT b.firstname, ', @sql, ' from user b
left join reimbursement c -- swapped join clause
  on b.id = c.user_id
left join reimbursment_limit d
  on c.acc_code = d.acc_code'); -- removed group by
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a1f8/7)

Comment: i can't open your sqlfiddle, no the left join is right i just wrong give record and i have been fixed the right is on b.id = c.user_id

Comment: The user_id in reimbursement_limit is both 1. That means both records are tied to user AAAAA

Comment: yes, you right user AAAAA must get 500000 and 700000

Comment: no , please see my complete right result in my question

Comment: What you're looking for is a pivot table. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table